# Tag queries containing specific word in R

Tags: r

Here is my sample data set:

```
query <- c("att plan","att price","attendant","attorney")
order <- c(1,2,3,4)
data <- data_frame(query,order)
```

I need to create a new column "Label". If the queries containing the word "att", they should be tagged as "att". Now I am using the grepl function.

```
data$Label = ifelse(grepl("att",data$query),"att",0)
```

However, the queries containing "attendant" or "attorney" will be also tagged. I only want to tag the "exact match" word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "word boundary" function of regular expressions:

```
data$Label <- grepl("\\batt\\b", data$query)
data
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#       query order Label
#       <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1  att plan     1  TRUE
# 2 att price     2  TRUE
# 3 attendant     3 FALSE
# 4  attorney     4 FALSE
```

You may also see it as `\\<` and `\\>`, providing the same results:

```
data$Label2 <- grepl("\\<att\\>", data$query)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?